# MSSQL: High-Availability, Witness and Principal down case

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

The Setup is as follows:

- 1x Principal
- 1x Secondary
- 1x Witness

If the Witness and Principal are gone (Hardware- or networkfailure), the secondary DB stays offline. I know this is by design. But if the Witness comes back up and the principal stays down, there is no switchover. Why?

Answer (score 0):

DO you have high safety with automatic fail over enabled in your mirroring settings? With out the automatic fail over enabled the witness wont enable the databases on the secondary server.

Comment: Yes, it's set up to switch automatically and works - IF the witness stays up all the time.